# Can I securely replace new lines with break tags like this?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, security

Can I securely replace `Environment.NewLine` with `<br />` like I am in the following extension method?

```
public static string HtmlBreaks(this string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) { return s; }
    return s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
}
```

I use it like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Details.HtmlBreaks())
```

And let me be clearer. ***Is this secure?*** ***Am I breaking any internet security guidelines by replacing text with HTML and then issuing the `Raw` method?*** Am I opening this website up to any attacks by this?

Comment: Why not it just a helper and where are you breaking any security it just your pure design option

Comment: @COLDTOLD, my primary concern is that I'm replacing text with HTML and then issuing the `Raw` method. I don't want any issues. I'm pretty sure it's safe, but I need some other people's opinions. Thanks for yours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not secure.  Take the example text of the details containing:

`<script>alert('a')</script>`

The `HTML.Raw` will output that as a script tag and the browser will execute the script.  If the user provides the details text, this allows them to inject script into your page (A basic XSS attack).

If you want to replace the newlines with `<br>` do it in your view.  For example, my controller might look like this:

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.Description = "Hello \r\n how are you today \r\n <script>alert('a')</script> \r\n";
return View(model);
```

In my view, I can do this:

```
@{ var lines = Model.Description.Split('\r');
   foreach (var line in lines)
   {
       @line.Trim() <br />
   }
 }
```

Comment: Okay, so let's go down this road. The data is in fact being entered by users on the site. I'm using MVC 4, how can I simply ensure that the data is secure going into the database so that I won't have to worry about the aforementioned?

Comment: @BigM your HtmlBreaks extension method could replace all < and > by &lt; and &gt; respectively, and then both \r\n and \n by <br/>.

Comment: You could split on a newline and then loop through the resulting array appending the <br> in your view.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to make sure that the SOURCE of the HTML is not a concern. In other words, if you are accepting INPUT from users and storing that in your database and then are using Html.Raw to display this, you can be opening yourself wide up for all sorts of problems.

IF the source of the HTML is contained and from a known and trusted source, you can reduce the risk greatly.

Essentially, it comes down to where is the HTML coming from. Using this information, you can make your best judgement as to whether or not you want to use @Html.Raw() and if you want/need to implement further filtering. The choice is up to you but now you know the risks.

Comment: Exactly, the OP didn't specify the source of the to-be-treated strings. If it is HTML content from untrusted sources, Koerner's answer is a must-see. Also, it should be noted that if users in different platforms are inserting content, new lines could be stored both as \r\n and as \n, and thus one Replace should be issued for each one of them.